# Pass parameter in a simple WCF POST

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I was reading the thread [How to pass parameter(s) to a WCF post method (a restful services)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830289/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-wcf-post-method-a-restful-services) and I have a similar problem, when I tried to send a `POST` request without parameters, it's working, but when I added a simple string parameter `(string a)`

**IServ**

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IServ
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Test", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string Test(string a);
}
```

**Serv.cs**

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)] 
    public class Serv : IServ
    {
        public string Test(string a)
        {
            return @"{
                        'widget': {
                            'debug': 'on'
                        }
                    }";
        }
    }
```

But, when the method has a parameter I got this error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is' Error deserializing the object of type System.String. Unexpected character 'C'. '. For more information, see the server logs. The stack trace of exceptions is:
```

> System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
>   dataContractResolver) en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message
>   message) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message
>   message) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) en System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Comment: Does the WCF Test Client error out too?

Comment: How are you calling the method?